# Increment UISlider by 0.2 in range 0 to 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uislider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increment UISlider by 1 in range 1 to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834140/increment-uislider-by-1-in-range-1-to-100)

I am new to iPhone,

How do I have my UISlider go from 0 to 2 in increments of 0.2?

```
slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 2.0;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 0.0;

- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"slider.value=%f",slider.value);
}
```

When i slide my log shows...

```
slider.value = 1.000000
slider.value = 1.123440
slider.value = 1.234550
slider.value = 1.345670
slider.value = 1.567890
.
.
.
```

I want slider value as 0.0 , 0.2 , 0.4 and so on...

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Seriously??  You asked the same question already...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your sliderChanged method, take the value from your slider, round it to the nearest 0.2, then set the value of your slider to this rounded value. This will snap the slider thumb to 0.2 increments.

You can round like this:

```
float roundedValue = roundf(value / 0.2f) * 0.2f;
```

(Thanks @koki)

Comment: How to round it to the nearest 0.2 ?

Comment: Is that your actual question, given that this is otherwise an exact duplicate?

Comment: float roundedValue = roundf(value / 0.2f) * 0.2f;

Comment: @jrturton u r welcome :)