# How to move / jump the UISlider THUMB directly to the next value while we are dragging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uislider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increment UISlider by 1 in range 1 to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834140/increment-uislider-by-1-in-range-1-to-100)
>   [Increment UISlider by 0.2 in range 0 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927591/increment-uislider-by-0-2-in-range-0-to-2-0)

In my **iPad app** i have used **uislider as a part.**

in that i have **3 points 1 2 3.**

as per ui design my **slider is too long (it should be in that much width)** in width,

So my requirement is jump the **Slider THUMB**

**`When user want to change the value from 1 to 2 , 2 to 3the Slider THUMB position directly jumps to the point2, and point 3 respectualy with out lagging. and viceversa.`**

How can we do it

Thanx in advance

Comment: Do some research, break some walls, and then ask for help.

Comment: try my code its work fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code..

```
float roundedValue = roundf(yourSlider.value / 1.0f) * 1.0f;    
[yourSlider setValue:roundedValue];
```

i hope this help you...

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
[mySlider setMaximumValue:3.0];
[mySlider setContinuous:YES];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (IBAction)sliderChangedAction:(id)sender {
    UISlider * mySlider = (UISlider*)sender;    
    [mySlider setValue:ceilf(mySlider.value)];

}
```