# How can I make a slider move in steps of 0.25?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a slider that have a min of 0 and a max of 8. 
I would like to move between 0 and 8 in steps of 0.25. 
Ex. 0 - 0.25 - 0.5 - 0.75 etc.

Can anyone please help me? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: UISlider.value is float so you could set fractions to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/setValue:animated: supports float as well...

float roundedValue = roundf(value / 0.2f) * 0.2f; (use this to round....)

See here for a similar problem
[Increment UISlider by 0.2 in range 0 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927591/increment-uislider-by-0-2-in-range-0-to-2-0)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up with the following code and it works just as I wanted.

    var roundedScaleSliderValue = round(scaleSliderValue.value * 4) / 4