# Move UISlider directly to a value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a `UISlider` with values from 0 to 5. I want the thumb to stop only at the exact values and not in between. Is moving the slider programmatically the only option? Or is there a property which governs this behavior?

Comment: There is a similar/identical question on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834140/increment-uislider-by-1-in-range-1-to-100

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function round to get the value from the slider

```
NSInteger value = (NSInteger)round(slider.value);
NSLog(@"Slider value is %d", value);
```